# ServiceStack Minification

Tags: servicestack

I have overridden the function GetVirtualFileSources() as indicated in the following link, but my files are not compressed: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/HTML,-CSS-and-JavaScript-Minification#minify-dynamic-razor-views

Please help to understand the problem.

Thank you in advance!

[image]
[image]

**EDIT**

GetVirtualFileSources() minified files and add Memory Filesystem, but when I make a request http://myshost/style.css I get the original file.

How to make the backend return the minimized file.

It's requet Raw:

```
GET /content/style.css HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:61923
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Referer: http://localhost:61923/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: ss-pid=1BFULq391BqiGZ4dwj3Z; X-UAId=2; com.cloudloto.lang=ru; ss-id=GaurYdBT7yDywtF3JTiM
```

**EDIT 2**

responce Raw:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/css
Last-Modified: Sat, 27 May 2017 23:22:08 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4,58 Win32NT/.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Startup-Errors: 1
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?ZDpcRG9jdW1lbnRzXExvdG9UZWFtXGxvdG9cbG90b1xsb3RvXGNvbnRlbnRcc3R5bGUuY3Nz?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 28 May 2017 20:55:01 GMT
Content-Length: 50176
```

I attached the file and not directly by the virtual path:

```
<link href="/content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

File just is minimized, the rest I do as the documentation.

[image]

```
public override List<IVirtualPathProvider> GetVirtualFileSources() {
            var existingProviders = base.GetVirtualFileSources();
            var memFs = new InMemoryVirtualPathProvider(this);

            var fs = existingProviders.First(x => x is FileSystemVirtualPathProvider);

            foreach (var file in fs.GetAllMatchingFiles("*.html")) {
                var contents = Minifiers.HtmlAdvanced.Compress(file.ReadAllText());
                memFs.AddFile(file.VirtualPath, contents);
            }

            foreach (var file in fs.GetAllMatchingFiles("*.css")
              .Where(file => !file.VirtualPath.EndsWith(".min.css"))) //ignore pre-minified .css
            {
                var contents = Minifiers.Css.Compress(file.ReadAllText());
                memFs.AddFile(file.VirtualPath, contents);
            }

            foreach (var file in fs.GetAllMatchingFiles("*.js")
              .Where(file => !file.VirtualPath.EndsWith(".min.js"))) //ignore pre-minified .js
            {
                try {
                    var js = file.ReadAllText();
                    var contents = Minifiers.JavaScript.Compress(js);
                    memFs.AddFile(file.VirtualPath, contents);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    base.OnStartupException(new Exception("JSMin Error {0}: {1}".Fmt(file.VirtualPath, ex.Message)));
                }
            }

            existingProviders.Insert(0, memFs);
            return existingProviders;
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't provided any info that could help identify the issue. Please always show the impl you're using in your question. First debug your custom GetVirtualFileSources() impl to confirm that this .css file is being minified and added to the Memory Filesystem, note the VirtualPath then make a direct request to that css file from Chrome to verify if it's minified, please show the HTTP Request in WebInspector only as the sources view may be auto formatted.

Comment: Please also include the raw HTTP Response Headers. Also your url says `http://myshost/style.css` but your HTTP Request says its requesting `/content/style.css`. Please specify the exact virtual path that's not being minified and please confirm if the exact file is being minified and added to the memFs in `GetVirtualFileSources()`.

Comment: I'm assuming the debug output you're showing me is for the file with the VirtualPath "/content/style.css"? The response is also being served by ServiceStack so it should work since ServiceStack sources its static files using the VirtualFileSources unless you've got some other configuration that's interfering with it but I can't tell from here because it's working as expected. Can you try the Service implementation in my answer and let me know if the file returned is the minified version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to requesting the **wrong case** in your Request `content/style.css` that was a different case that was added in the `InMemoryVirtualPathProvider` "Content/style.css".

To help with diagnosing static file issues try creating a Service that returns the file from the VirtualFileSources, e.g:

```
[Route("/files/{Path*}")]
public class DownloadFile 
{
    public string Path { get; set; ]
}

public object Any(DownloadFile request)
{
    var file = VirtualFileSources.GetFile(request.Path); 
    return new HttpResult(file);
}
```

Then calling this Service with the route `/files/content/style.css` to see if it's returning the minified file. If it doesn't find out what the type of `file` is.

Comment: @MherArsh and what's the type of `file`?

Comment: @MherArsh I mean the Type of `file` as in `file.GetType().Name`

Comment: I get minimized file for this request /files/Content/style.css, the files are not in content but in the Content, case-sensitivity, name of type "FileSystemVirtualFile"

Comment: @MherArsh Then you have something wrong with your AppHost state or configuration because it should be an instance of `InMemoryVirtualFile` that was added to `memFs` in your `GetVirtualFileSources()`. See if you've got any [StartUp Errors in ?debug=requestinfo](http://docs.servicestack.net/debugging#request-info). Also see if in you can retrieve the InMemoryVirtualFile in AppHost.Configure() with `VirtualFileSources.GetFile("content/style.css")`.

Comment: @MherArsh You have something else wrong/different in your AppHost which is interfering with the VirtualFileSources that is specific to your AppHost state/configuration that we wont be able to tell from here. You basically have to figure out why it's returning `FileSystemVirtualFile` instead of the `InMemoryVirtualFile` that was added in `GetVirtualFileSources()`.

Comment: the problem was solved when I anywhere in the file path specified "Content" with a large letter "C", it should have been, as the file path InMemoryVirtualFile was different - file.VirtualPath = "Content/style.css".

Comment: @MherArsh I've updated the answer to mention you were requesting the wrong case which I hope will help others requesting files using the wrong case.